How to create a gradient mask in PyTorch
I have a 2 X 2 tensor in PyTorch. I want the first row entries of this tensor (matrix) to be fixed, i.e., I do not want the first row entries to be parameters that are trained using gradient descent, and the second row entries be updated by the training process (using gradient descent). I saw online that I can use the register_buffer function in PyTorch to create a gradient_mask but I am not sure about the exact implementation.
matrix = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(2, 2))
register_buffer(‘gradient_mask’, ???)

Also, after I create this gradient_mask I do not know how to apply it to my variable: matrix. Any thoughts? Thanks.

If you want the values to be static, why are you making them a parameter?

There is an alternative option where to apply the gradient mask. You can zero gradients just before making the optimizer step.
    for _ in range(num_batches):

        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, targets)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        
        # apply zero mask before making optimizer step
        matrix.grad *= weight_mask
        optimizer.step()

Alternative if you need only one row to be static split data in rows and apply register_buffer:
import torch.nn as nn
import torch 

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.row1 = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, 2))
        self.register_buffer("row2", torch.zeros(1, 2))
        self.matrix = torch.cat((self.row1, self.row2))

